# Replace spaces in a file without changing those within fields

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, whitespace

I have a CSV file with lines like,

```
5213 , 1395429467 , A , r7.sn-a8au-hp5e.gvt1.com , 4.31.38.18 , 1460706280 , John Doe
```

I know how to replace spaces in the file: `:%s/ //g`. It changes the entire file which has the spaces.

I want the last element `$7` to maintain its spaces, so `John Doe` has to keep being `John Doe` and no `JohnDoe`.

All together, the expected output is:

```
5213,1395429467,A,r7.sn-a8au-hp5e.gvt1.com,4.31.38.18,1460706280,John Doe
```

Can some one help me on how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't get it. Are you only removing the spaces bordering the comma's?

Comment: @Bernhard to me it looks like the OP means spaces. I just edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Bernhard Yes, That's right mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just need to replace every `,` (that is, space + comma + space) with a single `,`:

```
sed 's/ , /,/g' file
```

Which retruns:

```
5213,1395429467,A,r7.sn-a8au-hp5e.gvt1.com,4.31.38.18,1460706280,John Doe
```

Comment: Oh yes, Stupid brain that always does'nt work in time. Thanks anyway.